# How to set value of transform property using javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found a similar answer to this on here, but it doesn't work for me. I am trying to make a scrolling single page layout, but by using css3 animations instead of jquery animate. What i'm shooting for is taking the variable set as the position of the hash and passing it into the transformX(). Here is what i have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<section id="wrapper">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">   
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-li"><a href="#intro">home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-li"><a href="#work">work</a></li>
                <li class="nav-li"><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                <li class="nav-li"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="home">
        <div id="intro" class="content">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="portfolio">
        <div id="work" class="content">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="about" class="about">
    </div>

    <div id='contact' class="connect">

    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</section>


<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;

}
```

and Relevant Javascript:

```
$(".nav-li > a").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         //calculate destination place
         var dest;
         if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
              dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
         }else{
              dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
         }

         //go to destination
         $('body').css('transform', 'translateY('+ dest +')');
                      //('-webkit-transform', 'translateY('+ dest +')');
                      //('-ms-transform', 'translateY('+ dest +')');
                      //('-moz-transform', 'translateY('+ dest +')');
                      //('-o-transform', 'translateY('+ dest +')');
         console.log(dest)
     });
```

I am definitely getting the right value for 'dest' as you can see with console.log(dest). Is this not possible?

Comment: You can also pass an object into the css method, so that way you don't have to create a new function for every single browser prefix.

Answer (score 9):

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ktfgf/)

Change your code from

`$('body').css('transform', 'translateY(' + dest + ')');`

to

`$('body').css('transform', 'translateY(-' + dest + 'px)');`

You need to specify a unit for translation. the -ve sign is to move the body upwards rather than downwards which is what you would expect.

Comment: I have a same problem and you answer unfortunately didn't help.
any idea?